# How to load csv file from hdfs into neo4j database?

Tags: neo4j, hdfs, cypher, graph-databases

I am using

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'hdfs://myfolder/docs/csv/name.csv'
```

but i get error : Invalid URL 'hdfs://myfolder/docs/csv/name.csv': unknown protocol: hdfs.

Is there any way to load csv from hdfs into neo4j. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

At this time that is not possible :

> CSV files can be stored on the database server and are then accessible
>   using a file:/// URL. Alternatively, LOAD CSV also supports accessing
>   CSV files via HTTPS, HTTP, and FTP.

As per the documentation at http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/.

You may be able to expose your hdfs filesystem over http (and then use a http:// url) but otherwise ... no.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Thanks. Could you please suggest any other easy way to do the same e.g using some drivers.

Comment: Since you obviously have Neo4j running somewhere (and that's always on top of a regular filesystem) ... the easiest way is to transfer your files to the import directory of the Neo4j server itself and use the file:/ protocol.

Comment: Thank you! I was doing the same but was looking for a better and direct approach.